# Looping over a list - is there a difference between the two methods?

Tags: python, list

Is there any difference in looping over a list by the following two methods?

`ls = [10, 40, 30, 50, 60]`

**Method 1**:

```py
for i in ls: 
    print(i)
```

**Method 2**:

```py
for i in range(len(ls)):
    print(ls[i])
```

Comment: Both does the same, but the first one is more **pythonic**

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you need to use list indexes, the second solution is necessary. Otherwise, the first solution is more pleasant to read.

Comment: The recommended approach, in that case, is to use `enumerate` as - ```for idx, val in enumerate(ls):```

Comment: `for idx, element in enumerate(ls):` if you need the indices as well. If you however only need the index value (without the actual element).. for some reason .. then maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Both work the same just the method 2 we have the index value as well of the list item. In method 1 the i variable iterates over the list. In method 2 we require 2 variable one the 
index variable the other the variable holding the length of the list